# Writing Test Class for Wrapper Class - Constructor not defined

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, wrapper-class

I am trying to write my test class for a wrapper class that just does not function. Right now my test class is coming back with

> Constructor not defined:
>   [OpportunityBrandWinListEditController].(ApexPages.StandardController)

I think it has to do first with my vf page using a custom controller and not a standard controller. I'm also wondering how I am going to handle the addition of new opportunities.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my controller, followed by the wrapper, followed by my test class that I have now:

```
public class OpportunityBrandWinListEditController {

public List<OpportunityBrandWinWrapper> wrappers {get; set;}

public Integer addItemCount {get; set;}

public Integer keyToDelete {get; set;}

public Integer mainKey {get; set;}

private List<Opportunity> toDelete=new List<Opportunity>();

public String bwOppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bwOppId');

public Opportunity bwOpp = [Select MRRPerUnit__c,
                            ID,
                            Account.Name,
                            AccountId,
                            Brand__c,
                            Units__c
                            From Opportunity
                            Where ID =:bwOppId];

public Opportunity firstForecastOpp = [Select MRRPerUnit__c, 
                                       ID, 
                                       Account.Name, 
                                       AccountId, 
                                       Brand__c,
                                       OwnerId,
                                       Type, 
                                       CloseDate,
                                       MatchonFlow__c,
                                       CreatedFromFlow__c
                                       From Opportunity 
                                       Where RelatedDesignWin__c =:bwOppId 
                                       Order by CloseDate ASC 
                                       Limit 1];

public Double totalUnits = 0;
public Double remainingUnits = 0;

public OpportunityBrandWinListEditController()
{
    mainKey=1;
    addItemCount=1;
    wrappers=new List<OpportunityBrandWinWrapper>();

    List<Opportunity> opps = [select id, 
                              CloseDate,
                              OwnerId,
                              Total_MRR__c, 
                              Units__c,
                              Total_NRR__c,
                              RelatedDesignWin__r.ForecastedUnits__c,
                              RelatedDesignWin__r.MRRPerUnit__c,
                              ForecastedUnits__c,
                              CumulativeForecast__c,
                              DiscreteExpectedUnits__c,
                              DiscreteTotalUnits__c,
                              Expected_Units__c,
                              Name,
                              Account.Name
                              from Opportunity
                              WHERE RelatedDesignWin__c =: bwOppId 
                              order by CloseDate ASC];

    for (Opportunity opp : opps)
    {
        wrappers.add(new OpportunityBrandWinWrapper(mainKey++, opp));
    }
}

public PageReference addItems()
{
    if ( (addItemCount>0) && (addItemCount<10) )
    {
        for (Integer idx=0; idx<addItemCount; idx++)
        {
            wrappers.add(new OpportunityBrandWinWrapper(mainKey++, new Opportunity
                                                        (DiscreteExpectedUnits__c = 0,
                                                         DiscreteTotalUnits__c = 0,
                                                         DiscreteTotalARR__c = 0,
                                                         DiscreteExpectedARR__c = 0,
                                                         CloseDate = firstForecastOpp.CloseDate.addMonths(((mainkey-1)*3)+1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1),
                                                         Name = 'Q' + firstForecastOpp.CloseDate.addMonths(((mainkey-1)*3)+1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1).month()/3 + ' ' + firstForecastOpp.CloseDate.addMonths(((mainkey-1)*3)+1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1).year())));
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public PageReference save()
{
    PageReference result = null;
    Boolean error = false;
    List<Opportunity> toUpsert = new List<Opportunity>();

    for (OpportunityBrandWinWrapper wrapper : wrappers)
    {

            {
                if((wrapper.opp.ForecastedUnits__c - wrapper.opp.DiscreteExpectedUnits__c - remainingUnits) <= 0){
                    wrapper.opp.Units__c = 0;
                    wrapper.opp.Total_MRR__c = 0;
                    remainingUnits = Math.abs(wrapper.opp.ForecastedUnits__c - wrapper.opp.DiscreteExpectedUnits__c - remainingUnits);
                }
                else {
                    wrapper.opp.Units__c = (wrapper.opp.ForecastedUnits__c - wrapper.opp.DiscreteExpectedUnits__c - remainingUnits);
                    wrapper.opp.Total_MRR__c = (wrapper.opp.ForecastedUnits__c - wrapper.opp.DiscreteExpectedUnits__c - remainingUnits) *  bwOpp.MRRPerUnit__c;
                    remainingUnits = 0;
                }
                wrapper.opp.RelatedDesignWin__c = bwOppId;
                wrapper.opp.StageName = 'Commitment';
                wrapper.opp.Probability = 1;
                wrapper.opp.Total_NRR__c = 0;
                wrapper.opp.AccountId = bwOpp.AccountId;
                wrapper.opp.Brand__c =  bwOpp.Brand__c;
                wrapper.opp.CreatedFromFlow__c = firstForecastOpp.CreatedFromFlow__c;
                wrapper.opp.MatchonFlow__c = firstForecastOpp.MatchonFlow__c;
                wrapper.opp.Type = firstForecastOpp.Type;
                wrapper.opp.Description = String.ValueOf(wrapper.opp.Units__c);
                wrapper.opp.CloseDate = firstForecastOpp.CloseDate.addMonths(((wrapper.key-1)*3)+1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
                totalUnits += wrapper.opp.ForecastedUnits__c;
                wrapper.opp.CumulativeForecast__c = totalUnits;
                wrapper.opp.OwnerId =  firstForecastOpp.OwnerId;
                wrapper.opp.Name = bwOpp.Account.Name + ' > Q' + wrapper.opp.CloseDate.month()/3 + ' ' + wrapper.opp.CloseDate.year();

                toUpsert.add(wrapper.opp);
            }

    }

    if (!error)
    {
        bwOpp.Units__c = totalUnits;
        bwOpp.Total_MRR__c = totalUnits * firstForecastOpp.MRRPerUnit__c;
        update bwOpp;
        upsert toUpsert;

        result=new PageReference('/' + bwOppId);
    }

    return result;
} 
}
```

Here is the wrapper:

```
public class OpportunityBrandWinWrapper {

public Integer key {get; set;}
public Opportunity opp {get; set;}

public OpportunityBrandWinWrapper(Integer inKey, Opportunity inOpp)
{
    key=inKey;
    opp=inOpp;

}

}
```

Here is the test class I have written:

```
@isTest private class testBWOppForecastJunction { static testMethod void myUnitTest()
{        
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator']; 
    User u3 = new User(Alias = 'newUser', Email='newuser10345@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='newuser10345@testorg.com');

    System.runAs(u3){

        List<sObject> accs = Test.loadData(Account.sobjectType, 'AccTestData');
        List<sObject> opps = Test.loadData(Opportunity.sobjectType, 'OppTestData');

        Opportunity opp1 = (Opportunity)opps[0];

        PageReference myVfPage = Page.vfOppBWForecast;
        System.Test.setCurrentPageReference(myVfPage); 
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('bwOppId',opp1.Id);
        String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bwOppId');
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(myVFPage);
        system.assertEquals(true,id==opp1.Id);

        OpportunityBrandWinListEditController bwOppTest = new OpportunityBrandWinListEditController(new ApexPages.StandardController(opp1));
        LIST<OpportunityBrandWinListEditController> lstAccLoc = bwOppTest.opps();

        for(OpportunityBrandWinListEditController oppList : bwOppTest.wrappers )
        {
            oppList.key != null;
        }

        bwOpp.createFR();
        bwOpp.insertRec();


        }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the compile error in the test by replacing:

```
OpportunityBrandWinListEditController bwOppTest
        = new OpportunityBrandWinListEditController(new ApexPages.StandardController(opp1));
```

with:

```
OpportunityBrandWinListEditController bwOppTest
        = new OpportunityBrandWinListEditController();
```

as your controller only has a no-args constructor as it is not written as a controller extension.

Not too sure what you mean by "how I am going to handle the addition of new opportunities"; if you are talking about in the test you would set the property and invoke the method and assert the result:

```
Integer initialWrapperCount = bwOppTest.wrappers.size();
bwOppTest.addItemCount = 5;
bwOppTest.addItems();
System.assertEquals(initialWrapperCount + 5, bwOppTest.wrappers.size());
// Assert wrapper content too perhaps
```